# Turn URL Object into URl string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I have a stringified object in my localStorage,

```
  const stringifiedURLObject = fromLocalStorage
```

I tried to JSON.parse  that string to normal Url Object. and I want to convert that object into Url string,

```
  // i want to turn this
  {
    pathname: 'user/[id]'
    query:  {
      mode: 'active'
      id: 'someID'
    }
  }

  // to this
  const normalPathURL = `/user/xxx?mode=active`
```

Then pass the string to redirect query

```
  {
    pathname: '/register',
    query: {
      redirect: normalPathURL,
    },
  }
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Do you have any control over the pattern of the param? meaning the bracket syntax. something like a `:` is a bit cleaner. Regardless I would have a route helper to handle this functionality for you

Comment: @JohnRuddell i dont know. i'm just following this example https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object

Comment: ok, thats fine. What I would do here is probably create a helper that converts the object to an actual `URL` so you can do whatever you'd like with it from there

Comment: On my way, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with javascript string templates:

```
 const parsedObject = {
    pathname: 'user/[id]'
    query:  {
      mode: 'active'
      id: 'someID'
    }
  }

  // to this
  // parsedObject.pathname.split('/')[0] extracts first part of pathname  
  const normalPathURL = `/${parsedObject.pathname.split('/')[0]}/${parsedObject.query.id}?mode=${parsedObject.query.mode}`
```

Comment: thank you. i'm thinking the same way. i just wondering if there is another way

Answer (score 0):

As an update, there's a solution here:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22025

```js
import Router from 'next/router';
import { resolveHref } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/router';
// for next 13
// import { resolveHref } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/resolve-href'

const exampleRoute = {
    pathname: '/work/[slug]',
    query: { 
        slug: 'project-foo',
    },
};
const [, resolvedAs] = resolveHref(Router, exampleRoute, true);
//       ^-- resulting path as a string
```

**NOTE:** when I tested the return type was defined as `string` for ``resolveHref, but it actually returned `string[]`, so I had to cast it as `any`